# Two Step Verification in ASP.Net MVC using Web Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, c#-4.0, session-cookies, two-factor-authentication

I implemented two step verification in a ASP.Net MVC page which uses Web Security by doing the following logic:

1) When the user login's first time and when clicks Next in the Login page,he is validated-

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    ......// Encrypt the password and storing it in a session
    ......// Then redirect to step 2 verification page...
}
```

and he gets redirected to 2nd step verification page where he would be asked to enter a security Q. If he gets it correct then a new cookie(Cookie2) is created, 
and the user is logged in using-

```
 .......//Decrypt the password
_webSecurity.Login(username, decryptedpassword, false)
```

and then he is redirected to his home page.

2) Next time when he tries to login to the app, there is a check to see if the cookie(Cookie2) which is created in the 2nd step is existing or not. If it exists, then he is redirected to the Home page directly and if its not existing then he is again asked to enter security Q.

So if we see the implementation here, i am actually logging the user into the app only if he gets 2nd step verification valid. In order to implement this, i am creating a cookie and storing the password in a session.

Can anyone let me know if we can code this in a better way?I am guessing we can do this without using sessions and cookies.

Any ideas/suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks,

WH